# I keep getting a warning when I put an array in a foreach loop

Tags: php

Here is my code.

```
function displayTweets($object){
    $myArray = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
    foreach ($myArray["statuses"] as $tweet){
```

It gives me a warning when I use line 3 of my code. The $object passed in the parameter is a json object and I am trying to for loop through it and display tweets. The code at first doesn't produce warnings but then out of no where it will and it pops my page with a warning box. How can I stop this warning message? Is it okay to use $myArray["statuses"] ?

Comment: KeyMaker13  check `$myArray` contains `status` index or not. You can use `isset()`, `!empty()`, `array_key_exists()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if `$myArray` actually contains the `statuses` key before using it.

```
if(isset($myArray['statuses'])) {
  // $myArray contains statuses, execute the for loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
function displayTweets($object){
   $myArray = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
   if(array_key_exists("statuses", $myArray) {
      foreach ($myArray["statuses"] as $tweet){
      // Your code
      }
    }
 }
```